# I have a list that takes the form Fname Lname, Address, BirthYear. How to iterate thru list and sort by BirthYear in ascending order

Tags: python, list, sorting

HOW DO I SORT THIS BY BIRTHYEAR IN ASCENDING ORDER? I'm distance learning student and have no help. I have a .txt file with this form: I'm trying to get that .txt in a list and sort it by birth year.

```
Brett Finch, 1839 Third, 1992
David Edwards, 290 Locust, 1985
Mia Palm, 33 Birch, 1980
```

I pieced this from multiple sources and it's only getting worse! Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

```
lstneedssorted = []  
f3 = open("file3.txt")  
print("\nMerged Doctors Data: ")  
Count = 0  
for lx in f3:  
    print(lx.rstrip())  
    lx = lx.strip().split(",")  
#strVal = lx  
lstneedssorted.sort([lx[0], lx[1], lx[2]])  
print(lstneedssorted)
```

Comment: `lx` is just one row, not all the rows. There's nothing to sort.

Comment: You never put anything in `lstneedssorted`.

Comment: The code I found starts with empty list then appends into it. It is a file handling assignment that needs a sort function. So I've already merged 2 .txt files into 3rd. Now I'm trying to read 3rd .txt file into list and sort by birth year in ascending order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append each row to the `lstneedssorted` list.

You can use the `csv` module to automatically parse the CSV file, instead of using `.strip().split(',')`

When sorting, you use the `key` option to specify how to get the sort key from each item. In this case, the date is `line[2]`.

```
import csv

lstneedssorted = []
with open("file3.txt") as f3:
    c = csv.reader(f3)
    for lx in c:
        lstneedssorted.append(lx)

lstneedssorted.sort(key = lambda line: line[2])
print(lstneedssorted)
```